# How do I embed javascript (to open dialog) in PDF in Report Builder in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-generation, delphi-xe2

I need to show an Adobe PDF Reader print-dialog when someone opens this PDF through our webportal.

Now I stream a PDF through my existing webportal made in Delphi XE2. I generate the PDF's in Waler's TExtraDevices, a component that extends Report Builder 14.07 for Delphi.

I read somewhere, that I can embed JavaScript in a PDF to trigger the print-dialog to show.

**How/where do I inject/place the JS in the Waler TExtraDevices PDF generator?** It IS an option to use the native PDF generation of Report Builder itself (but I'll have to check if they support embedding subsets of fonts, because the first versions of their PDF engine produced too large PDF's). **So an alternative question may be: How/where do I inject/place the JS in the native PDF generator of Report Builder?**

I've checked the manuals, the web and StackOverflow but can't find anything about how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind a solution which involves a separate post-process, you could use a library like [Debenu QuickPDF](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/) to update the PDF to add a Javascript action which opens the print dialog on document open.  They have a trial version which would enable you to verify that it works with your specific PDFs.